# How to compare two arrays with two inputs in python in a guessing game

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I need help with a project I'm working on to expand my knowledge of python. I enter which character I want to be replaced and it replaces it with another character that has been entered in a second input.

This bit I have worked out, it's the next bit I can't do. I need to check if the one in the second input matches the equivalent in the second array. I made a little diagram below:

```
list1 = [abc, bdc, eea] #visible to the user
list2 = [123, 243, 551] #the answers

input1 = a #what the user whats to replace 
input2 = 1 #what it needs to be replaced with
```

**is input 1 in list one?** #already done myself
**is the same location in list2 equal to that in input2?**

Comment: I don’t really get what you are trying to do. Can you provide a full example of what is happens and what should be the result? Also, if you have figured out the first part, please post that, so we can see what’s going on and so that you can actually show that you have done some work.

Answer (score 1):

Use strings and `enumerate`:

```
list1 = ["abc", "bdc", "eea"] #visible to the user
list2 = ["123", "243", "551"] #the answers

input1 = "a" #what the user whats to replace
input2 = "1"
for ind, ele in enumerate(list1):
    one, two = ele.find(input1), list2[ind].find(input2) # get index for both
    if one != -1 and one == two:  # if indexes are the same and ele.find(input1) is not -1
        print("Correct guess")
        list1[ind] = ele.replace(input1, input2) # replace letter with number

print(list1)
['1bc', 'bdc', 'ee1']
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood, you are trying to compare 2 lists of string after converting the input user strings with some kind of encryptation. In that case I would do something like this:

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
conversion_dict = {str(elem): index+1 for index,elem in enumerate(alphabet)}

def encrypt(string, conversion_dict):
    value = ''
    for letter in string:
        number = conversion_dict.get(letter)
        if not number:
            print("Letter {} can't be encoded".format(letter))
            return None
        value += str(number)
    return value


list1 = ["abc", "bdc", "eea"]
list2 = ["123", "243", "551"]
list1_encrypted = [encrypt(string, conversion_dict) for string in list1]
print("User input: {}".format(list1))
print("Encrypted user input: {}".format(list1_encrypted))
print("List1_encrypted is equeal to List2? {0}".format(list1_encrypted == list2))
```

The output is:

```
User input: ['abc', 'bdc', 'eea']
Encrypted user input: ['123', '243', '551']
List1_encrypted is equeal to List2? True
```